# Repeat the set of Sequence of xml elements without xmlwrappers

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to create an XML from the Jaxb from the java class

having a XML structure as below:

```
<A>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
</A>
```

Since the sequence of the attribute b,c,d repeats with XML wrappers. Below is the sample java code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;    

    ...(setters and getters)
        }
```

With the above java class I am able to generate the below XML: 
**

```
<A>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>

</A>
```

But I am sequence of the b,c,d has to repeated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you want A to have a list of b,c,d and not single instances of them.

Comment: yes the sequence of b,c,d should be maintained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xml you provided, would correspond to a class that looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name="b", type = String.class),
            @XmlElement(name="c", type = String.class),
            @XmlElement(name="d", type = String.class),
    })
    private List<String> letters;
}
```

Update to reply in the comment:

In order to use custom classes for the list's elements, I would do something like this:

I would create an interface Letter (which doesnt specify much in the example):

```
public interface Letter { }
```

Then class A would be:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name= "A")
public class A {
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name="b", type = B.class),
            @XmlElement(name="c", type = C.class),
            @XmlElement(name="d", type = D.class),
    })
    List<Letter> letters;

    public A() {}

    public A(final List<Letter> letters) {
        this.letters = letters;
    }
}
```

and B, C, D would be like the following:

```
public class B implements Letter {
    @XmlValue
    String b;

    public B() {}

    public B(final String value) {
        this.b = value;
    }
}
```

To get the xml from the POJOs, here is a simple main for demo purposes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            B b = new B("hello");
            C c = new C("hey");
            D d = new D("hi");
            List<Letter> letters = Arrays.asList(b,c,d);
            A a = new A(letters);

            marshaller.marshal(a, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answer was useful, but i needed toward a user classes but you have given with string. and also how to set the xmlelements using java...?

Comment: Will reply in an update of the answer for convenience

Comment: @ramesh027 do you still face challenges with it?